# Finding a local temple in USA

Tags: temple, worship

I live in the NE USA. There are many temples and shrines near where I live. The problem is that all of them were founded by immigrants from India. Therefore, they exist to serve their communities. 
What is the best way to seek out a local temple or shrine under these conditions if you are from the West?

Comment: are you looking for a hindu temple? if so, whats the problem if they were founded hindus from India or somewhere else?

Comment: 1) It can be a bit dis concerning to be the only white guy in the temple.

Comment: based on my experience, nobody would give you a second glance if you are a white guy at a Hindu temple in the US.  The priests and admin folks may even be extra helpful.

Comment: I'm glad you've had good experiences. I've had the door slammed in my face at a temple I will not mention.

Comment: Also, the language issue can be a problem. Hard to feel spiritual when everyone about you is talking in a language you don't understand. I understand these places are for the people that financed them and I have no issue with that. It would be nice to find a temple where the congregation uses English. I don't think there are five such temples in North America.

Comment: I'm sorry you had a bad experience.  I have seen people of Indian origin conduct worship in english - but not at the main shrine.  Most worship is in sanskrit which very few modern Hindus understand.  You wouldn't have any problem at large established Hindu temples.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that you were ill-treated, which is quite sad. I stayed for 3 months in Halifax, Canada, and was a regular visitor to the [hindu temple](https://hindutemple-halifax.org/) there. I've personally seen many western people mingle amongst the immigrant population there and the congregation was in English. The aarti books were also transliterated in English. I do wish you good luck, hopefully someone from NE USA comes up with a nice answer! :)